# Javascript to strip ending html tags?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a web page that is auto-generated by a CRM (Netsuite) and I do not control the html generated in a fair amount of the page. I would like to remove a handful of closing and opening tags, so that objects are rendered in the same row vs. in rows above and below each other.

```
</tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr>
```

The problem I have is that doing the following breaks the forms on the page, causing all of the buttons to fail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var bodyHtml = document.getElementById('content_area').outerHTML;
    bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('</tr></tbody></table></td>\n</tr>\n<tr 
      valign="top">\n<td width="100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" 
      cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr>','<!-- worked -->');
    document.getElementById('content_area').outerHTML = bodyHtml;
   });
</script>
```

Is there another way to remove html tags via javascript that doesn't mal-form the rest of the dom?

Comment: You'd be better off modifying the DOM by moving the elements, instead of trying to modify the actual markup

Comment: Ok, so how do I do that? Let's suppose I have <table><tr><td>content 1</td></tr></table><table><tr><td>content 2</td></tr></table>. You are suggesting I try to move the second <td> to end up with the following: <table><tr><td>content 1</td><td>content 2</td></tr></table><table><tr></tr></table>?

Comment: Yes, I've created an answer to show the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will take the example from your comment, and append the `content 2` `td` right after the `content 1` `td`

```js
let contentOne = document.querySelector("table:nth-of-type(1) tr td");

let contentTwo = document.querySelector("table:nth-of-type(2) tr td");

contentOne.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', contentTwo);
```

```css
tr td {
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Couple of points to note, you may want to change the selectors. Make use of IDs if you can.

Secondly, you may want to clear up the empty table / rows when your done.